# Android Studio Debugger Not in Sync with Source Code

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

When I try to debug my application with Android Debugger, I run into strange problem. The debugger steps into wrong line of code (Sometimes into comments too). Clearly, debugger is not in sync with the current code. I observe this problem when I debug into the framework code (Ex: Activity.java). The options I tried to fix this are,

- Clean/Rebuild
- Change a few lines in build.gradle and sync
- Delete Build folder from the project directory structure

None of them seems to work, any help is appreciated

Comment: setup compileSdkVersion correctly in your build.gradle file

Comment: That probably means the SDK that you have the source for is not the same version as the one on the phone.

Comment: How to update SDK version on the phone?

Comment: This has started happening to us here too, multiple times. None of what we try help. We're running AS 1.3.2